# Long labels make the size of Zingchart piechart tiny

Tags: size, pie-chart, label, zingchart

I am trying to generate a pie chart with Zingchart library. The thing is if I have long labels the pieces of the pie chart become very small. I do not mind placing this information to the legend in case it is the only solution, but how then I can force the library to not display these labels near the chart pieces?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a couple ways you can approach this. To remove the labels on each of the chart pieces, you can set the `value-box` object to have a property of `visible : false`. 
Demo :  http://demos.zingchart.com/view/XEJLFO96

Another suggestion would be to break up long lines of text with newlines \n to shorten the width of each label.
Demo : http://demos.zingchart.com/view/JKUGHGMD

I'm on the ZingChart team, so feel free to reach out to us with any other questions.

Comment: Concerning replacing spaces with \r\n: it works well in your example but in some other case we can have more pieces or several pieces can be of a small size, that i why the problem stays. So, thanks a lot for the 'visible : false' thing, it is the real solution in the described situation!